# Raid 10 Centos 7 failure after power cut suddenly

Tags: centos7, raid10, corruption

I have 1 server that using RAID 10 software. However, after recent power failure the server no longer can boot and stuck at grub rescue.

Using ls command for all device n the server does not detect the content thus cannot reinstall grub.

Using rescue mode to at least assemble the raid also fail.
[assemble scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5GHP.gif)

I run this command : mdadm --examine --scan --verbose
and it shows below;
Is it still recoverable?

[mdadm examine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mMNo.gif)

Assemble command also fail to assemble the raid.

[assemble fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSNLR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mdadm --assemble` command is wrong, as specified a partition (`/dev/sda1`) rather what seems the correct component device (`/dev/sda`). Having said that, the `mdadm --assemble --scan -v` command does not find any valid superblock.

From `mdadm --examine` it seems you are using Intel's integrated RAID. Maybe the powerloss reset the CMOS and now your BIOS is passing the raw disk without the correct superblock.

Anyway, for a more in-depth explanation we need more info. Please give us moe info about your RAID setup and share the output of:

- `lspci`
- `lshw`
- `lsblk`
- `pvs`
- `vgs`
- `lvs`
- `mdadm -E /dev/sd[abcd]`